# How to fix broken syntax highlight in Visual Studio 2022 UI (different colors)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, syntax-highlighting

How to fix these annoying different color errors which came after some recent updates? I definitely remember that there were no such errors a couple of months ago.

Question is about color highlight, not the green curly underscore. For example keyword `var` has boldness and navy color in one string and no boldness and light blue color in other string. Light blue I use for identifiers but `var` is keyword.

[image]

Different color and boldness highlight errors:

1. `var` keyword
2. `a` local variable
3. `p` parameter
4. `IA` interface & `M` method

---

In VS2019 all is OK

[image]

Comment: Does it work properly if you start VS in [safe mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe?view=vs-2022)?

Comment: Safe mode resets colors to default and no errors. But strangely after step by step customizing this errors occur again.

Comment: Which customization step breaks it?

Comment: Hi,@MDspb. What is your version of Visual Studio? Have you tried creating a new blank application and editing the same code to see if there are any highlight errors? Do you have any third party nuget packages?

Comment: VS2022 17.9.4. I found that VS sync my settings in the cloud. This is the cause of strange and unpredictable resets which I saw. Also I try VS2019, I remember that VS2019 as much more stable and without many annoying bugs of VS2022 with search, windows borders etc. And without highlight bug. And, yes, VS2019 does not have any of errors from op post. Strangely I also found that VS2019 _initially_ produce the same highlight errors as VS2022 after start. But (sic!) after several seconds VS change this for correct highlighting.

Comment: I'm not sure but suppose that Roslyn in VS2019 can correctly decouple code text in the end. Not instantly. VS2022 has lost this ability. Why? Idk. Overall VS2022 has many UI bugs that live year to year.

Comment: @HuiLiu-MSFT Also in brand new console app with net8 in vs2022 there all the same wrong coloring errors. No nuget packs.

Comment: @MDspb. As Andrew mentioned. Can you share with me your custom steps to reproduce this issue? What setup steps did you take? I did not reproduce the issue when I tested the code in a Visual Studio 2022 console application. What is your project type?

Comment: @HuiLiu-MSFT Just simple console app. Idk how to reproduce this. But if this issue is only mine I think that something wrong with my VS2022 installation. Maybe some damaged json config files with settings. Because I just set colors/boldness for different code members — and get highlight errors as showed in pics.

Comment: It could indeed be related to a corrupt or incorrect configuration file. Here are some troubleshoot steps:
1. If possible, reset Visual Studio settings (you can go to Tools > Import and Export Settings > Reset All Settings).
2.Reinstall or repair Visual Studio to help replace any corrupted or missing configuration files.
  3. If the problem persists, can you share with me the steps to set color/bold for different code members.
Or can you cancel the setting?

Comment: @HuiLiu-MSFT I've found that identifier customizing breaks all of this. I do just 1. Reset all settings. 2. Change only identifier format. And get all of described errors. Interesting, when I do not change Identifier setting, but customize all other — everything looks ok. So I can try just not customize Identifier. Maybe it could be as workaround. But it would great if I see this bug fix or at least cause of this.